# Use Spring Boot Spring Security configuration in Grails 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grails, spring-security, grails3

I'm looking to learn Spring Security with Grails but I can't find any intensive course that is built with Grails. My question is, since Grails 3 is built on top of Spring Boot, can I use Spring Boot Spring Security configuration for my Grails 3 app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

There are several security related Guides at http://guides.grails.org.

Some documentation you might find helpful:

https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html

https://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/index.html

Comment: I've searched at length and couldnt find any documentation of how to configure `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in Grails 3 with SSC. I've seen the documentation too.

Comment: What configurations are you trying to manipulate that are not covered by the plugin's configuration properties?

Comment: @styl3r Your question makes no mention of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter `.  You should post a more specific question that articulates what you are trying to accomplish and what you have tried.

Comment: Your question was "...can I use Spring Boot Spring Security configuration for my Grails 3 app?".  The answer is "yes".